# Проблема с event.stopPropagation в мозиле

Tags: javascript

Проблема с мозилой, выскакивает ошибка "TypeError: window.event is undefined" в хроме все ок.
Проблема в том, что в мозиле надо писать с большой буквы, а в хроме с маленько что делать?

```
showPhoto: function(obj_user){  
        if (window.event.stopPropagation) {
            window.event.stopPropagation()
        } else {
            event.cancelBubble = true
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Firefox нет `window.event`. Это видно из описания обьекта `window` [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window). Используйте нормальное навешивание обработчика событий через `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` для IE < 8), и получайте обьект события непосредственно в обработчик.

Пример:

```
function test(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    //e = обьект события.
    e.stopPropagation();
}

// Навешиваем обработчик
var lnk = document.getElementById('lnkTest');
if(lnk.addEventListener)
    lnk.addEventListener('click', test);
else
    lnk.attachEvent('click', test);
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/QHvh4/1/

Comment: как тогда остановить всплытие в Firefox?

Comment: обновил ответ